# “Name spacing” random/unique IDs

Tags: random

I am building a web app that generates unique IDs for user-created resources, so URLs or just IDs can easily be shared. I would like to “namespace” the IDs in some way, while keeping the IDs a reasonable length and looking consistent.

There are currently three hierarchical types of resources: a file, a collection (group of related files), and a project (a group of related collections).

Currently my scheme uses a 12 character nanoID (excluding underscores and dashes) with a prefix, e.g., [fcp]-x17Y8rSk03al. Where f, c, p stand for file, collection or project.

I don’t quite like this scheme and would prefer all the IDs to look indistinguishable to the user, while still being able to figure out resource type from the ID on the backend.

Possible solutions I’ve considered:

1. Different ID lengths for each of the 3 resources. This is easy to expand in the future if I add more resource types but it’s inconsistent.
2. Add a numerical prefix like xxxx-(nanoID), where xxxx are just random numbers. For example, 0000-4999 is a file, 5000-7999 is a collection, 8000-8999 is a project and the rest is reserved for future uses, or something like that. The second dash is optional or of course.
3. Add a random prefix like above but in base64 but I don’t want to use - or _, so base 62 I guess? This is the one I like most.

With approaches 2 and 3 I’m not sure how to split up the range into the three resource types and leave room for future additions.

All these solutions seem a bit hacky and I’m worried I’m reinventing the wheel. Is there some kind of standard/convention or a “cleaner” way to do this? Maybe generate the IDs with some scheme so that their characters/digits/bits can be manipulated/combined in a specific way to compute what type of resource it is? But that also sounds unnecessarily complicated.

(I’m using python and JS but ultimately my question is completely language agnostic.)

**EDIT:**

Based on suggestions in the comments, I spent some time playing around with encryption. I tried the [Fernet symmetric encryption](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/) scheme but the results are absurdly long and start similar due to the time stamp.

A limitation I have is that the user-facing IDs (not the internal ones) must be reasonably sized and represented in base62 (not base64, since I need them to be URL safe and they can't include dashes or underscores for project-related reasons).

While base64 doesn't fit into the byte paradigm either, I found base62 trickier when working with encryption since log(62) is not an integer. I tried block ciphers like AES, but then I was playing tricks padding/manipulating the internal IDs and ending up with 128-bit (32-byte) encrypted IDs that don't fit into base62 very well. I tried AES-CRT (stream mode) but I couldn't figure out how to get it to work in a bit-level mode, not byte-level mode.

I think ultimately what I want is *obfuscation* not encryption. I'm not after "security by obfuscation" (I know that's not a thing), I simply don't care about the users figuring out the internal database keys (UUIDs or whatever other scheme I end up with), it's an open-source project with publicly accessible data anyway.

I don't want all my IDs to look like `{one of three letters}{base 62 string}`, I want them to look more generic to the user while still being able to retrieve the type of the resource on the backend so I can figure out where to look in the database.

I tried generating a same-length key in base62, then XORing it with the base62 internal ID (which starts with F, C, or P) after padding (e.g., with a 15-character ID in base62, you can have at most 90 bits). The IDs will naturally still have one of 3-4 possible starting characters when converted back to base62. Better but not ideal. I'm sure I can play more tricks shuffling the characters etc, but at this point, I'm just reinventing the wheel again.

Comment: _"All these solutions seem a bit hacky and I’m worried I’m reinventing the wheel"_ - you are.

Comment: _"Is there some kind of standard/convention or a “cleaner” way to do this"_ - yes: use your own structured format, then encrypt the whole string using a symmetric algorithm so only your web-server can encrypt and decrypt the strings - users will see them as entirely random, unpredictable strings, while your application code can decrypt them to get the raw (e.g.) integer ids and char/string type-tags.

Comment: Note that the more opaque you make the identifier the less convenient it is to use when troubleshooting.  Also, when using randomness check how the birthday paradox affects things (you likely need more bits than you'd naively think).

Comment: @Dai I have updated the post in response to your comment, thanks for giving me somewhere to start looking.

Comment: @SamMason thanks for the comment, I'm starting to realize the opaqueness issue as well while debugging. I've been using NanoID's collision calculator to help with the birthday problem (https://zelark.github.io/nano-id-cc/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with this for a few days, this is what I ended up settling on: the primary keys (PKs) are [KSUIDs](https://github.com/segmentio/ksuid), which have a timestamp and can help with cluster-indexing the database. They are also base62 encoded by default and are quite popular.

To generate the "public facing" ID, I prefixed the internal PK with a base62 character depending on resource type, and used [FF3-1](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-38Gr1-draft.pdf) format-preserving encryption (FPE), which preserves the length and alphabet of the plain text.

Sample python implementation with [this package](https://github.com/mysto/python-fpe) for FF3-1 and [this implementation](https://github.com/svix/python-ksuid) of KSUIDs.

I am also prefixing all my public IDs with `myapp-` so that they're easily identifiable in the wild and easy to share.

```
from ksuid import Ksuid
from ff3 import FF3Cipher
import os

B62 = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
key = os.urandom(32).hex() # private key, must be kept secret
tweak = os.urandom(7).hex() # tweak isn't generally kept secret
c62 = FF3Cipher.withCustomAlphabet(key, tweak, B62)


def get_pubid(pk, prefix):
    return f"myapp-{c62.encrypt(f'{prefix}{pk}')}"


def get_pk_from_pubid(pubid):
    # Strip the "myapp-" prefix
    prefixed_pk = c62.decrypt(pubid[6:])
    return prefixed_pk[1:], prefixed_pk[0]


prefixes = ["A", "B", "C", "X", "Y"]
for p in prefixes:
    pk = str(Ksuid())
    pubid = get_pubid(pk, p)
    pk_2, prefix = get_pk_from_pubid(pubid)
    print(f"Start: {pk} (prefix: {p}), end: {pk_2} (prefix: {prefix}). pubid: {pubid}")
```

This outputs:

```
2S8304ZYcFVbGp13iFhbWH6QQN7+prefix:A -> myapp-EdBSaWdn1TDuhJRjQFs0eJMzI7A8 -> 2S8304ZYcFVbGp13iFhbWH6QQN7+prefix:A
2S8308uvY4xtw6v5I3oGZHbqGuZ+prefix:B -> myapp-F7hednJmX8O97MDgr5V4etIgSj5O -> 2S8308uvY4xtw6v5I3oGZHbqGuZ+prefix:B
2S830601VnYWSN5L0ruwATrEd6D+prefix:C -> myapp-7PQnxdB9Mh5KOwwBdC5HvuQKn7Xc -> 2S830601VnYWSN5L0ruwATrEd6D+prefix:C
2S83040fgqhCI1ZAU1WnyY8NKmy+prefix:X -> myapp-WL4HRQIQTqmpkwDCyAxq67tPULY3 -> 2S83040fgqhCI1ZAU1WnyY8NKmy+prefix:X
2S83094Ip58G41mbBU9O1zUHlxw+prefix:Y -> myapp-oYutnwjC634B224z1vbfqIVj3dtn -> 2S83094Ip58G41mbBU9O1zUHlxw+prefix:Y
```

The only problem is that KSUIDs are quite long (32-bit timestamp + 128 bits of entropy, leading to 27 base62 encoded characters). If you don't need that much entropy (My use case doesn't), you could subclass the `Ksuid` class like this to get something shorter (say, 64 bits of entropy):

```
import math
from baseconv import base62
class KsuidShort(Ksuid):
    """Shorter KSUID-like k-sorted unique IDs"""
    PAYLOAD_LENGTH_IN_BYTES = 8
    BYTES_LENGTH = Ksuid.TIMESTAMP_LENGTH_IN_BYTES + PAYLOAD_LENGTH_IN_BYTES
    BASE62_LENGTH = math.ceil(BYTES_LENGTH * 4 / 3)
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        """Creates a base62 string representation"""
        return base62.encode(int.from_bytes(bytes(self), "big")).zfill(self.BASE62_LENGTH)
```

With an 8-byte payload, the PKs are 16 characters long and the public IDs are 17 characters long. Since KSUIDs only have a second resolution in their time stamps, we can look at collision probabilities from the birthday problem:

```
import math

p = 0.01
for Nbytes in [5, 6, 7, 8, 16]:
    N = math.sqrt(2 * 2 ** (Nbytes * 8) * math.log(1 / (1 - p)))
    print(
        f"Need to generate {math.ceil(N)} ids with a {Nbytes}-byte payload in one second"
        f" before the probability of collision is {p*100}%"
    )
```

The results:

```
Need to generate 148664 ids with a 5-byte payload in one second before the probability of collision is 1.0%
Need to generate 2378621 ids with a 6-byte payload in one second before the probability of collision is 1.0%
Need to generate 38057931 ids with a 7-byte payload in one second before the probability of collision is 1.0%
Need to generate 608926882 ids with a 8-byte payload in one second before the probability of collision is 1.0%
Need to generate 2615321040553095168 ids with a 16-byte payload in one second before the probability of collision is 1.0%
```

8 bytes is more than sufficient for my application, I could probably get away with 7 or even 6, but I'm okay with a slightly longer ID.

(P.S. This simplifies the math a bit, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4673169/how-to-estimate-collision-risk-of-partially-random-strings) for a better treatment of time-stamped unique IDs.)